# AngularJS: ng-show="user" falsey, ng-show="!!user" truthy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a user on the current scope, set by my current controller.

```
$scope.user = user;
```

Selectively showing/hiding a `<div>` based on the existence of this user is not working as I would expect, rather an exception is being thrown.

**Does not work:** `ng-show="user"`

```
<div class='row' ng-show="user">
    ...
</div>
```

**Works:** `ng-show="!!user"`

```
<div class='row' ng-show="!!user">
    ...
</div>
```

What is happening with `ng-show` which results in `ng-show="user"` not being truthy?

I am using `angular.1.2.6` from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js

**Exception thrown:**

If I use `ng-show="user"`, then I get the following exception in my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at Ma (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:14:240)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:185:464)
    at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (<anonymous>:778:50)
    at h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:99:211)
    at h.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:101:256
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:33:182)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:36:378
```

This error disappears when I use `ng-show="!!user"`

**User object:**

This is the `user` object which is on the `$scope`:

```
{
  "state": "",
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "code": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read",
  "id_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "authuser": "0",
  "session_state": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "prompt": "none",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "g_user_cookie_policy": "single_host_origin",
  "cookie_policy": "single_host_origin",
  "response_type": "code token id_token gsession",
  "issued_at": "1391059385",
  "expires_at": "1391062985",
  "_aa": "0",
  "status": {
    "google_logged_in": true,
    "signed_in": true,
    "method": "AUTO"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the failure. Seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/pMFjL/

Comment: `$scope.user` is being set on a Google+ oauth2 callback, which I can't replicate on jsfiddle/plunker etc

Comment: @hassassin - added the `TypeError` exception to the question

Comment: Opened angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6051

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) expects an expression to evaluate and will "convert" to Boolean using this function:

```
function toBoolean(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    value = true;
  } else if (value && value.length !== 0) {
    var v = lowercase("" + value);
    value = !(v == 'f' || v == '0' || v == 'false' || v == 'no' || v == 'n' || v == '[]');
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  return value;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/834d316829afdd0cc6a680f47d4c9b691edcc989/src/Angular.js#L962

So you shouldn't just use an object. You could keep using `!!user` or maybe `user.someattr`

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise this! Thought it checked for non-null

Comment: I wonder if there isn't a case to be made for an additional `if (typeof value === 'object')` check?

Answer (score 2):

The !! operator basically converts the JS object to a boolean.

Check out the following example:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'false';
    $scope.boolean = !!$scope.user;
}
```

We create a user object, containing for example the string false, and it's boolean representation by calling the !! operator. Since $scope.user has a value that is not null, the !! operator will convert it to true. However angular will convert the string 'false' to the boolean value false, and thus hide the div.

We can test this in the following way:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-show="boolean">
        test boolean
    </div>

    <div ng-show="user">
        test user
    </div>

    <span>{{boolean}}</span>
</div>
```

Which outputs the following:

```
test boolean
true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FTXn3/

@EDIT

Since we are talking about a user object and not a string, as stated by the error message you receive, the !! does the conversion to the boolean (=primitive) for you.

Comment: is it not safe to expect a non-null object to evaluate to truthy?

Comment: well, to be honest it's the first time that I see that error!